# Glide equivalent in flutter

Tags: android, image, flutter, android-glide, checksum

Im my SDK sample app in native android, an image is loaded using Glide library as follows.

```
private void updateProfilePhoto(BadgeUIEntity badgeUIEntity) {
    String profilePhotoChecksum = badgeUIEntity.profilePhotoChecksum();
    String profilePhotoUrl = badgeUIEntity.profilePhotoUrl();
           if (profilePhotoChecksum != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(profilePhotoUrl)) {
            try {
                RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.signatureOf(new ObjectKey(profilePhotoChecksum));
                Glide.with(this)
                        .applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                        .load(profilePhotoUrl).into(ivProfilePhoto);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Timber.v(e);
            }
        }}
```

How can I render the same image in flutter?
I have no idea what to do with this checksum in Flutter.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package.

Comment: I tried Cached network image, but I don't know how to supply the checksum into it.

Comment: What is this checksum?

Answer (score 5):

[`cached_network_image`](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) is the equivalent of Glide or Picasso for Flutter.

It will use a default caching logic but if you want you can pass your own `CacheManager` to it. I am not sure why you need the checksum, but I assume is something related to cache management.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it named [Optimized Cached Image](https://pub.dev/packages/optimized_cached_image/#optimized-cached-image) which is loading images from network, resizing, and caching them for memory sensitivity. This resizes and stores the images in the cache based on parent container constraints and hence loads images of lower size into memory. This is heavily inspired by the [cached network image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) library.

This library exposes two classes for loading images

`OptimizedCacheImage` which is a 1:1 mapping of `CachedNetworkImage`.

`OptimizedCacheImageProvider` which is a mapping of `CachedNetworkImageProvider`.

Comment: is this better because it optimizes and resizes the image? im having the same issue even qhen jsing cached-network-image. the lag when scrolling up or down and reloading the image is not good ux